# `play run` and `play dist` have different home pages?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I use play2 to create a default scala app:

```
play new test
```

Then:

```
play run
```

Visit `http://localhost:9000`, I can see:
[image: home with play run]

But when:

```
play dist
cd dist
unzip test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip -d .
cd test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
./start
```

The home page will be:

[image: home page play dist]

Why they are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is to run the server in development mode (`run`) and the other in production mode (`dist`), that's why the pages shown are different.

Comment: The template can check if you are running in dev or prod mode :)

Comment: Checkout the github page showing it : https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html